# TwitterBootstrap 3 Carousel not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I seem to be having problems with Bootstrap's carousel. The last time I implemented one was when I was using Bootstrap 2.xx. Ripping from the 2.xx example code pages worked fine. But when I do the same, the carousel does not seem to work. Doesn't slide, nothing. I have included Bootstrap 3 CDN and the paths work. I have also included Jquery at the bottom of the page, the one they gave with the code, that is also still a live link. 
Any solutions/advice is highly appreciated.

Thankyou

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Veyern Gaming</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
    <div class="container">
    <!--Navbar-->
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/index.html>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Forum</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Vote</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Stats</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <!--Image Slider-->
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
          <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon-prev"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon-next"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
      </body>
    <html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap's JavaScript components depend on jQuery, therefore you have to load the library *before* you load the components.

From the Bootstrap docs:

> Plugin dependencies
>
> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you
>   include plugins individually, make sure to check for these
>   dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery
>   (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files).

There's no reason your closing part can't look like:

```
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Scripts-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
<html>
```